# preventDefault() is not stopping the page/form to reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

Trying to stop reloading of the page with preventDefault() but it is still reloading the page. I've used it before and it was working too. But I'm not able to find the fug in this code. Please help. TIA.

> HTML

```
<form method="post" id="submitform">
Student ID:<br>
<input type="text" name="sid"><br>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
</form>
```

> jquery

```
  $(function () {
  $('#submitform').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $('#submitform');
  var formData = $(form).serialize);
  $.ajax({
  url: location.pathname,
  method: 'POST',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: what is `submitform` ??? a **class** or **id** ???

Comment: You missed last closing bracket => )

Comment: share your form opening code `<form ........>`

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look now.

Comment: Note that submitting a form using enter works unreliable among commonly used browsers

Comment: Could you paste the code in the Stackoverflow post again? At the moment it contains a syntax error on line 5 (`unexpected ), expecting ;`), and thus when we try to run it, it doesn't work

Comment: change your last line `}` to `});`

Comment: it worked. Thanks, @Matee Gojra and Is there any way I can still send the data without reloading it

Comment: you are already sending data without reloading the page... using AJAX Object

Comment: yeah exactly but my node js doesn't catch the values sent by ajax when I use preventDefault() otherwise it works fine

Comment: Oh, it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Snippet

```
  $(document).on('submit', '#submitform', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
  url: location.pathname,
  method: 'POST',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine as long as you clean up your syntax.

```js
$('#submitform').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $('#submitform');
  var formData = $(form).serialize();

  console.log(formData);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="submitform">
  Student ID:<br>
  <input type="text" name="sid"><br> First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br> Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```